# Get the username of a new user account into the activation email for django-registration?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

Is there a way to do this? I'm not seeing it in the [activation_email.txt template context](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/quickstart.rst) but someone might have figured it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/d36a38202ee3/registration/models.py#cl-207) - email is sent using `self.user.send_email`, so you could just add:

```
'user': self.user,
```

to the `ctx_dict`.